# GUI freezes after a few seconds in this dialog based application

Tags: c++, winapi

im a beginner trying to understand the reason why the GUI freezes after very few seconds here.
Try run it and see what i mean..
Shouldn't it keep printing Hello1 Hello2 Hello3 Hello4 and Hello5 forever?
To be clear: it is SetWindowText() that stops doing the job, so it is the GUI that freezes.
What i mean is, the application keeps running, it is just the "show text" part, that crashes.
I know this because i debugged it before posting.
So what am i missing? Why is it freezing?
Do you know?
Thanks in advance

Here is main.cpp:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

HINSTANCE hInst;

void sayHello(HWND handle)
{
    BOOL working = true;
    while (working)
    {
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello1");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello2");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello3");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello4");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello5");
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return TRUE;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_BTN_QUIT:
                    EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
                    return TRUE;

                case IDC_BTN_TEST:
                    HWND handle = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, 1003);
                    sayHello(handle);
                    return TRUE;
            }
    }

    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst = hInstance;

    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DialogProc);
}
```

Here is resource.h:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define DLG_MAIN 101
#define IDC_BTN_TEST 1001
#define IDC_BTN_QUIT 1002
#define ID_CONTROLSTATIC 1003
```

Here is resource.rc:

```
#include "resource.h"

DLG_MAIN DIALOGEX 6, 5, 194, 106

CAPTION "Test Application"

BEGIN
  CONTROL "&Test", IDC_BTN_TEST, "Button", 0x10010000, 138,  5, 46, 15
  CONTROL "TEXT HERE", ID_CONTROLSTATIC, "Static", 0x10010000, 35, 35, 50, 8
  CONTROL "&Quit", IDC_BTN_QUIT, "Button", 0x10010000, 138, 29, 46, 15
END
```

Comment: That doesn't explain the reason it hangs. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite looop here:

```
void sayHello(HWND handle)
{
    BOOL working = true;
    while (working)
    {
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello1");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello2");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello3");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello4");
        SetWindowText(handle, "Hello5");
    }
}
```

Add a condition to exit the loop, e.g. `if(something) working = false;`

If you want it to keep printing forever, you will need to at least add a timer between the commands, because as it is it prints the messsages so fast that you will not really tell it's happening.

Comment: Sure i forgot to mention that sayHello() is just a stand-in for another longer function. Whatever, how should i code it to work without freezing?

Comment: Run the work on another thread and leave your UI thread available to process UI events.

Comment: Yes Raymond that is exactly what i'm trying to do now. But i never worked with threads in my life. So to save my time now, i would need someone to write the working piece of code for me. I'm sure it's not a too big effort considered how tiny my application is. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure of all windows GUI programs is a message loop, which is something like:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Your program waits in the `GetMessage` call until a message arrives, then processes the message (which eventually ends up in your window or dialog procedure), then returns to `GetMessage` to wait for the next message.

In your program the message loop is hidden inside the call to `DialogBox`, but it is there.

When you click on `IDC_BUTTON_TEST` the function `sayHello` never returns.  So control never returns to the message loop, so you don't process any more messages and your program seems to have hung.

If you want to do work in parallel with the message loop you have at least two choices:

1. Create a timer.  When you receive a `WM_TIMER` message you do a bit of work (like display the next string in your list), then return to the message loop and wait for more messages.  The more work you do on each timer tick, the less responsive your application will be.
2. Create another thread.  This can run continuously without interfering with the message loop, but is potentially more complicated because you have to worry about synchronisation between your threads.

Comment: It makes sense. So you are saying the message loop has some sort of time deadline that makes it hang that way, correct? Ok. I started googling around about WM_TIMER and threads and i found some things i'm going to read shortly. In the meanwhile could you show me how you would implement the WM_TIMER or the thread way? I mean could you show the code? Thanks a lot

Comment: The message loop doesn't have a deadline as such.  If you never reenter the message loop then you never handle messages, so your dialog is unresponsive.  To use a timer call [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the timer (maybe when the button is pressed) and handle [WM_TIMER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `DialogProc`.